# Removing a group if a particular value occurs in it more than 1 times in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
   ID  Value
    1     a
    1     a
    1     b
    2     a
    2     b
    3     a
```

I want to remove all the ID from dataframe where Value 'a' has occured more than once. So above dataframe will look like:

```
       ID  Value
        2     a
        2     b
        3     a
```

I want to do this in python. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with : *creating a boolean mask by groupby and transform*:

```
df[df.groupby(['ID'])['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('a').sum()==1)]
```

---

```
   ID Value
3   2     a
4   2     b
5   3     a
```